# generate custom id with conditions while inserting records to sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, uniqueidentifier

How can I generate custom ids upon inserting records base on a condition? For example, I have a `donor database program` which accepts donations from `non-alumni` and `alumni`. Custom id from an alumni should start on `A00001` and for non-alumni is `N00001`. And to note, the record that will be inserted will come from another table which records came from an excel file.

Any help or clarifications would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
 DECLARE @Table TABLE ( ID VARCHAR(20) );

-- Non alumni
INSERT  INTO @Table
        ( ID )
VALUES  ( 'N00011' )

INSERT  INTO @Table
        ( ID )
VALUES  ( 'N00012' )

INSERT  INTO @Table
        ( ID )
VALUES  ( 'N00013' )

-- Alumni
INSERT  INTO @Table
        ( ID )
VALUES  ( 'A00011' )

INSERT  INTO @Table
        ( ID )
VALUES  ( 'A00012' )

INSERT  INTO @Table
        ( ID )
VALUES  ( 'A00013' )

-- Insert Alumni
INSERT  INTO @Table
        ( ID
        )
        SELECT  'A' + RIGHT('00000'
                            + CAST(MAX(RIGHT(ID, LEN(ID) - 1)) + 1 AS VARCHAR(10)),
                            5)
        FROM    @Table
        WHERE   LEFT(ID, 1) = 'A'

-- Insert Non Alumni
INSERT  INTO @Table
        ( ID
        )
        SELECT  'N' + RIGHT('00000'
                            + CAST(MAX(RIGHT(ID, LEN(ID) - 1)) + 1 AS VARCHAR(10)),
                            5)
        FROM    @Table
        WHERE   LEFT(ID, 1) = 'N'
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that the id from the source table is non existent. So the id should be generated like from an empty column